# How to handle device removal in Linux Kernel Driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

You have done it a thousand times: you unplug some USB equipment and any device associated with that USB equipment is removed by the driver. Any program that uses some previously opened file handle will get an error. Somehow most Linux drivers take care of that.

I am currently struggling to implement the same in a simple driver. My driver creates a character device. When the device is opened, I set the `private_data` member of `struct file` to the address of some management data that exists once per character device. That management data also includes a mutex that I use to synchronize operations like `read`, `write`, and `ioctl`.

The problem now arises when the USB equipment is unplugged. I must not free the memory where that management data lives. First, any currently running `read`, `write`, or `ioctl` should finish. Any such running call will likely also hold a lock on the mutex and will attempt to unlock it. So the memory where the mutex lives will be accessed.

Any `read`, `write`, or `ioctl` call subsequent to unplugging the equipment should fail, so every such call must read some variable telling whether the USB equipment is still plugged in or not. Again, that variable must live somewhere and the memory where it lives must stay allocated as long as there are open file handles.

Long story short, it seems to me that I must do some sort reference counting: The management data must stay allocated until all file handles have been closed. I could implement that myself, but I have the feeling that I would reinvent the wheel. Such a thing must already exist, I'm not the first to have this problem.

Does Linux internally keep track of the number of open file handles? Can I define a callback that is called when all file handles have been closed? Is that even a viable thing? What is the proper way to remove a character device from the system?

Global variables shall not be avoided, since any number of USB devices can be attached.

Comment: You need to do a few reference counting. One is to prevent driver gone, while it’s being used. Another is to prevent device gone if being opened. Maybe you need more, but without code it’s hard to say.

Comment: For USB, you may get away with just checking (with a mutex locked) if the device is disconnected in the file operation handlers, and killing in-flight URBs in the disconnect handler, as is done by the prototype "usb-skeleton" driver code in "drivers/usb/usb-skeleton.c".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by 0andriy, I have used reference counting to track the number of open file handles. Per character device, I have added a new struct containing a `mutex`, a `kref`, the `cdev` struct, and a pointer to further data. I use `kref_get` to increase the reference counter when a new file handle is opened. Accordingly, I use `kref_put` when file handles are released or the USB equipment is unplugged.

Since all I/O operations (`read`, `write`, `ioctl`, etc.) use the mutex, I can safely change the pointer to `NULL` when the USB equipment is unplugged. The I/O operations then start reporting errors.

The `kref` reference counter only returns to zero when the USB equipment is unplugged *and* all file handles are closed. So then I can also free the memory of the new struct.

This seems to work. It was a surprise that the `cdev` struct is referenced by file handles. It seems to be needed as long as there are open file handles.

But I'm still surprised that I had to go down this route. It seems redundant to implement that in every driver.

**UPDATE:** As it turns out, doing reference counting yourself is dangerous. In particular counting the number of open file handles is wrong. There is a whole reference-count-based garbage collection system in Linux and you need to use it.

For example, Linux calls `cdev_get` when a process opens a character device and `cdev_put` when the process exists and the file handle is still open. Unfortunately, the call to `cdev_put` would occur after the file handle's release function. As we would free the memory after the last file handle has been released, we would end up freeing the underlying memory of the `cdev` and the `mutex` before `cdev_put` is called.

The solution is to assign a parent to the `cdev` via `cdev_set_parent`. The parent `kobject` will have its reference counter increased whenever `cdev_get` is called and decreased after `cdev_put` is called. The kobject then can have its own release function which frees any memory required by the cdev. Basically I replaced the kref in my struct with a kobject.

Lesson learned: don't do reference counting on your own. Use the existing hierarchy of `kobject`s, which is the kernel's way of doing garbage collection.

**UPDATE2:** It turns out, we reinvented the wheel again. The `device` struct includes a release hook, which is called when the internal kobject reached a reference count of zero. This is the mechanism typically used in the kernel to release resources associated with an device - including the device struct itself.

I was looking for a release hook in the `cdev` struct. There was none. But it turns out I should have looked one step up in the hierarchy for such a hook.

Long story short: Use `cdev_device_add` in combination with the `device` release hook. `cdev_device_add` will internally call `cdev_set_parent`, so the `device` becomes the parent of the `cdev`. Those are the mechanism other kernel drivers (e.g. evdev) use to release their resources.

Comment: Updated the answer with the final solution based on the kobject hierarchy.

Comment: Have you ever asked yourself why this is done for only a couple of drivers in the kernel out of hundreds? I.o.w. what makes your code so special? And again, you haven’t showed the code to see what you are doing there.

Comment: Yes, I have. I have no answer to that question though.

Comment: I mentioned in my original question that I'm not doing anything special. Reference counting was suggested - but the only safe way of reference counting is via the fact that a `cdev` is also a `kobject`. Maybe there is a better approach that I haven't found yet.